# Realm crash on iOS 10 with 'String'

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, realm

I have recently released a new version of our app and during beta testing, it's crashing on all iOS 10 devices but not other versions. Since we have Crashlytics, we found a strange crash message in the backend that we can confirm is the reason all iOS 10 crashing since it's 100% iOS 10 and there's like 40 of them.

It reads as follows:

Fatal Exception: RLMException
Property Article.id is declared as String, which is not a supported managed Object property type. If it is not supposed to be a managed property, either add it to `ignoredProperties()` or do not declare it as `@objc dynamic`. See https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/Object.html for more information.

And here's the object:

```
class Article: Object {
    
    @objc dynamic var id: String = UUID().uuidString
    // others...

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
}
```

As you can see, this is perfectly nomral and runs fine on other iOS. In Realm's doc, it LITERALLY SAYS to use String with `@objc dynamic` and there's no way it's unsupported. I suspect there's nothing special about `Article.id`, and since `Article` starts with `A`, it happens to be the first String property of all realm Objects. Maybe somehow all Strings stopped working on iOS 10?

Can anyone offer some advice or insights?(Please don't say things like drop iOS 10 support. For now, we need it.)

Comment: Which version of Realm do you have? It started happen to me on version 4.4.1 :(

Comment: Yes for us it was also 4.4.1. Turns out we have another app where it runs fine on iOS 10, and it was using 4.3.2. The problem disappeared when we downgraded it to Realm 4.3.2. @goodliving

Comment: What about 5.x.x version? Did you try?

Comment: @goodliving No, as we couldn't afford updating such a pivotal library by a major version right before entering beta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a Realm's bug. We happen to have another app that runs just fine on iOS 10, and after some inspection we realized that it was using Realm 4.3.2, instead of 4.4.1. After we downgraded Realm to 4.3.2, this problem disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

We ran into the same issue a couple of times, trying to drag Realm fully into Swift. This is not really *the* answer but more of a workaround we've had success with when needing backward compatibility.

It's an ObjC object, not Swift.

There's something going on with the bridging, perhaps conforming to NSCopy'ing or something along those line, so just change it to read

```
@objc dynamic var id = NSUUID().uuidString
```

See the Getting Started Guide in the [Models](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#limitations-models) section which calls for using NSUUID

> NSUUID: An object representing a universally unique value that bridges
> to UUID; *use NSUUID when you need reference semantics or other
> Foundation-specific behavior.*

Comment: But doesn't NSUUID give a String as well? UUID.uuidString and NSUUID.uuidString are both Strings, and once the string is generated, UUID or NSUUID, no matter which, is discarded. What's the reason behind using NSUUID instead of UUID?

Comment: @Nicholas One is an NSString and the other is Swift String. They are not discarded at all when they are a primary key. There are some subtle differences which is why the Apple docs spell that out. Remember - a LOT of Realm is still backed by ObjC and depends on Foundation bridging. It has worked for us with older builds (older versions of Swift and the OS) so give it a shot and see what happens.